# How can I provide delay between the animation effects

Tags: android, android-animation

I made an xml layout, the layout has basically four buttons,the buttons will be provided with animation effect, they would be swiped in, when their corresponding activity starts, Now the animation part is easy, the problem I'm having is how can I create a delay between each animation?I mean each time a button swipes in, there should be some time lag after that. Is using thread an option here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use a "fake" animation to implement the delay, for example, changing alpha from 100% to 100% with a duration of 1 second. It actually does nothing, but the animation takes time, and that's what you want. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

You might be looking for something like this?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#attr_android:startOffset